# Android wear emulator has any sensor?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

Does an Android wear emulator have any virtual sensors? If not, how do I get the sensor simulator to work in the android wear emulator?

I am trying to collect pedometer data from an android wear emulator into my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Emulators don't have any sensor since it's pure hardware on the wearable. I don't think you have any solution just yet such as the mock positions. Maybe in the days to come, but for now you're stuck with buying a smartwatch, I'm affraid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an virtual advice -> open it -> params -> virtual sensors